# hovercard quick hover in and out issue

Tags: jquery, hover

I found a hovercard script by 'Design with PC'. It's quite good and I already applies it nicely on the website.

However, I discovered that if one hovers on and out in quick succession, script doesn't work properly. It happens also on the demos on project website. One problem with it is that the 'caption' (the link the hover works with) disappears from the 'popup'. Other, more problematic (at least for me) is that it looses z-index information. On the homepage of my website I'm using nivo-slider and hovercard popup, when opened, covers the slider partially. When I do hover in/out slowly, everything is fine. But when I do it quickly, part of nivo-slider content appears 'above' the hovercard popup

I'm intending to comment on script author's page with the question but it may take a moment for him to reply. Any ideas for a quick fix?

Answer (score 0):

I found that using the 'delay' setting seemed to mitigate against this problem. I've set mine to 400ms.